# Issues Adding Package in Julia

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, ijulia-notebook

First off, I'm new to Julia, so I'm still getting used to the language.

I'm using Jupyter and I'm trying to add "SpecialPolynomials".
This is what I keep getting:

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add("SpecialPolynomials")
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

Resolving package versions...
Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package SpecialFunctions [276daf66]:
 SpecialFunctions [276daf66] log:
 ├─possible versions are: [0.7.0-0.7.2, 0.8.0, 0.9.0, 0.10.0-0.10.3] or uninstalled
 ├─restricted by julia compatibility requirements to versions: [0.7.0-0.7.2, 0.8.0] or uninstalled
 └─restricted by compatibility requirements with SpecialPolynomials [a25cea48] to versions: [0.9.0, 0.10.0-0.10.3] — no versions left
   └─SpecialPolynomials [a25cea48] log:
     ├─possible versions are: 0.1.0 or uninstalled
     └─restricted to versions * by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions 0.1.0

Stacktrace:
 [1] #propagate_constraints!#61(::Bool, ::typeof(Pkg.GraphType.propagate_constraints!), ::Pkg.GraphType.Graph, ::Set{Int64}) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.2\Pkg\src\GraphType.jl:1007
 [2] propagate_constraints! at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.2\Pkg\src\GraphType.jl:948 [inlined]
 [3] #simplify_graph!#121(::Bool, ::typeof(Pkg.GraphType.simplify_graph!), ::Pkg.GraphType.Graph, ::Set{Int64}) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.2\Pkg\src\GraphType.jl:1462
 [4] simplify_graph! at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.2\Pkg\src\GraphType.jl:1462 [inlined] (repeats 2 times)
 [5] resolve_versions!(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.2\Pkg\src\Operations.jl:317
 [6] #add#100(::Bool, ::typeof(Pkg.Operations.add), ::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}, ::Array{Base.UUID,1}) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.2\Pkg\src\Operations.jl:962
 [7] #add at .\none:0 [inlined]
 [8] #add#25(::Bool, ::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::typeof(Pkg.API.add), ::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.2\Pkg\src\API.jl:99
 [9] add at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.2\Pkg\src\API.jl:69 [inlined]
 [10] #add#24 at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.2\Pkg\src\API.jl:67 [inlined]
 [11] add at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.2\Pkg\src\API.jl:67 [inlined]
 [12] #add#21 at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.2\Pkg\src\API.jl:65 [inlined]
 [13] add at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.2\Pkg\src\API.jl:65 [inlined]
 [14] #add#20(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::typeof(Pkg.API.add), ::String) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.2\Pkg\src\API.jl:64
 [15] add(::String) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.2\Pkg\src\API.jl:64
 [16] top-level scope at In[20]:2
```

I've tried solutions for similar issues I came across online.

I tried removing Special Functions.
I tried using
`] gc` + `enter`.
But many of these posts are saying to start an issue on git, can anyone see what would be causing this problem?

Answer (score 7):

There just isn't a supported version intersect for `SpecialFunctions`/`SpecialPolynomials` and Julia 1.2 which you are running. You should update to Julia 1.4, which (at time of writing) is the current supported release.

Comment: Thanks! I got it working :) I manually uninstalled 1.2 and then downloaded 1.4 from Julialang.org.
Just so I know for the future, is there an easier way to do this from Jupyter?

Comment: To do what? Download a new version of Julia? No.